# Rank of a left-orthogonal decomposition $A^T=UB^T$

Tags: matrices, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, orthogonality, matrix-rank

I've got a rather simple question, but couldn't find an answer to it: Say $A\in\mathbb R^{m\times n}$ can be decomposed according to $$A^T=UB^T\in\mathbb R^{n\times m}\tag1$$ for some left-orthogonal (i.e. $U^TU=I_k$) $U\in\mathbb R^{n\times k}$ and some $B\in\mathbb R^{m\times k}$. Why do we know that it must hold $k\le m$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First note that it can hold with $k > m$. Consider the example
$$A^T = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0&1 \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix} = I_3 \cdot \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0&1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

Also note that it can only hold for $k \leq m$ if $A^T$ is of rank $k$ or less. The reason is because the rank of a product $AB$ of matrices is at most $\min(\text{rank}(A), \text{rank}(B))$. If $\text{rank}(A^T) > k$ and $A^T = U B^T$ with $U \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times k}$, then we arrive at a contradiction, because the rank of the right-hand side can at most be $k$, because the rank of $U$ is $k$.

**EDIT:** The claim that it must be that $k \leq m$ if $A^T = U B^T$ when $U$ is right-orthogonal is also false. Let 
$$A^T = [1], ~ U = \begin{bmatrix} 1/2 & 1/2 & 1/2 & 1/2 \end{bmatrix}, ~ B = U^T$$
Note that it is true that $n \leq k$ in this case since otherwise we would have two matrices $U$ and $U^T$ each of at most rank $k$ multiplying to give a rank $n$ matrix.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Okay, I guess the left-orthogonality of $U$ implies that its columns span a $k$-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb R^n$ which in turn implies $k\le n$ and hence $\operatorname{rank}(UB^T)=\dim U\mathcal R(B^T)\le\min\left(\dim\mathcal R(B^T),\dim\mathcal R(U)\right)\le k$. Most probably I made a mistake in my assumptions. If we assume $U$ to be right-orthogonal (i.e. $UU^T=I_n$) instead, does the claim become true?

Comment: @0xbadf00d See my edits.

Comment: I'm sorry, I guess in the context where this question came to my mind (with the left-orthogonality as in the question) it is assumed that $k=\operatorname{rank}A$. Then it's clearly trivial that $k\le m$.

Comment: @0xbadf00d Then I guess I don't understand the question: $k = \text{rank}(A) \leq m$ because $m$ is the number of rows in $A$. Is this what you mean? BTW, when this is the case, the desired decomposition is not only possible, but it is also possible with $B^T$ being an upper-triangular matrix by using the Gram-Schmidt process. Also, why the downvote?

Comment: Yes, I guess QR-factorization or SVD-decomposition is possible. The reference I was reading missed to state this assumption, but meanwhile I deduced that this assumption must be in force from the context.

Comment: Regarding the downvote: I've no idea. I didn't downvote your answer, but I'll give you an upvote now to compensate it.